# passing array through xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

In the code below I am trying to pass all the marks entered by the user to  another page for execution but only the value of the first mark entered in the table is  send.Is there a way to send all the values of the marks entered rather than just the first value;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function send(){
                var marks=document.getElementById("marks").value;
                var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest()
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                {
                if(this.readyState==4 &&this.status==200)
                {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=this.responseText;
                }
                };
                xmlhttp.open('GET','mark.php?marks='+marks,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>name</td>
                <td>marks</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" ></td>
                <td><input type="number" id ="marks"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" ></td>
                <td><input type="number" id ="marks"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" ></td>
                <td><input type="number" id ="marks"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button onlick="send()" >submit</button>
        <div id='result'><p></p><div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `ID` attributes must be unique - so having tow or more `marks` is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `ID` attributes from the number inputs you can obtain a reference to all of them using `querySelectorAll` with a suitable pattern. Once you have that nodelist reference you can iterate through to find the values and use as you need.

You should be able to process `$_GET['marks']` in `marks.php` quite easily after that..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <script>
            function send(){
                var marks=[];

                /* Find all the input elements that are considered `marks` and assign their values to an array */
                Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]') ).forEach( input=>{
                    marks.push( input.value );
                });


                var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest()
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                        if( this.readyState==4 &&this.status==200 ){
                            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=this.responseText;
                        }
                    };
                    /* prepare the array.. could alternatively use JSON format */
                    xmlhttp.open( 'GET', 'mark.php?marks=[' + marks.join(',')+']' );
                    xmlhttp.send();
            }

            /* bind an event listener to the button */
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
                document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',send)
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>name</td>
                <td>marks</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" /></td>
                <td><input type="number" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" /></td>
                <td><input type="number" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" /></td>
                <td><input type="number" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button>submit</button>
        <div id='result'><p></p><div>
    </body>
</html>
```